# After upgrading application from MVC3 to MVC4, telerik extension grid throwing null reference error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-grid

I have upgraded MVC3 application to MVC4 application and changed target framework to 4.0. no build errors. But at run time System couldn't load a page where telerik extension grid was present.

I do get below error

> Index Out Of Range Exception in GridBuilder

So, I have changed telerik extension grid to kendo grid but do get below error.

> at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument
>   argument, ExceptionResource resource)    at
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.set_Item(Int32 index, T
>   value)    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext.get_RequestContext()
>
>   at Kendo.Mvc.UI.NavigatableExtensions.GenerateUrl(INavigatable
>   navigatable, ViewContext viewContext, IUrlGenerator urlGenerator)
>
>   at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.CrudOperationBuilderBase`1.SetUrl()    at
>   Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.CrudOperationBuilderBase`1.Action(String
>   actionName, String controllerName, Object routeValues)    at
>   Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.CrudOperationBuilderBase`1.Action(String
>   actionName, String controllerName)

Answer (score 0):

Telerik extensions for ASP.Net MVC is supported MVC versions 1,2 and 3 only.

[http://docs.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/getting-started-installation-instructions.html#Installing][1]

When you upgrade legacy application from MVC3 to MVC4, need to tell compiler to compile third party DLL like telerik extension using version 3 by modifying root web.config file.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" 
         publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```